# Custom gradle script for Detekt with multi-module project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, detekt

I'm trying to create a custom gradle task that will run the different detekt profiles I have setup.

Here is my Detekt config:

```
detekt {
    version = "1.0.0.RC6-4"

    profile("main") {
        input = "$projectDir/app/src/main/java"
        output = "$projectDir/app/build/reports/detekt"
        config = "$projectDir/config/detekt-config.yml"
    }

    profile("app") {
        input = "$projectDir/app/src/main/java"
        output = "$projectDir/app/build/reports/detekt"
    }

    profile("database") {
        input = "$projectDir/database/src/main/java"
        output = "$projectDir/database/build/reports/detekt"
    }

    profile("logging") {
        input = "$projectDir/logging/src/main/java"
        output = "$projectDir/logging/build/reports/detekt"
    }

    profile("network") {
        input = "$projectDir/network/src/main/java"
        output = "$projectDir/network/build/reports/detekt"
    }
}
```

And here is what I'm trying for the custom gradle task:

```
task detektAll {
    group = 'verification'

    dependsOn 'detektCheck'
    doLast {
        println "\n##################################################" +
                "\n#        Detekt'ed all the things!  Go you!      #" +
                "\n##################################################"
    }
}
```

I need to add `-Ddetekt.profile=app` and the others for each profile.

How can I accomplish this?